# Accessing Google app engine datastore objects using hibernate

Tags: hibernate, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Is there a way to access google app engine datastore objects using hibernate hql?

I have an existing application and I am migrating it to google app engine and want to store my object in data store. I can see all the way to user JDO /JPA but not hibernate.

I already used JAP in java app engine application to access datastore object and this time I want to use hibernate as the existing application already uses hibernate and want to just migrate it to google app engine.